# How to animate a HighChart chart that is created dynamically?

Tags: animation, highcharts

I would like to draw each point immediately when it's added. But it waits and draws all the points at the end. Before trying to use the built in API I used a queue to add those tasks, but isn't the API support that? See the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7dx7u34v/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        animation: {
            duration: 10000
        }
    },
});

$('#update').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({});
     for(var i = 0; i < 500 ; i ++){
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.series[0].addPoint([i,50 * (i % 3)])
    }
});
});
```

Comment: So you need to print point by point, like an animation?

Answer (score 0):

Animation is by default true if you not explicitly define its options .In your case your animation duration is higher than the plot time while adding point. If you reduce animation time ,it will be shown

```
   animation: {
            duration: 1000 
        }
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/7dx7u34v/2/)

Comment: I think that the requested effect should be somehow like print point by point, instead of all of them in one time.

Comment: This works only for a small number of points. If I have a lot of points it doesn't work.